# How would I explain to a Japanese that I like to hear their rolling "R"?

Tags: translation, word-requests

Ok I've been listening to this girl broadcasting her webcam and sometimes she will start talking in a sort of a "rolling R" dialect, or like a "yakuza" type of speaking with rolling R's.  Is there is specific term for this in Japanese?

I can tell it's almost like an "alpha" way of speaking.  I just don't know how to explain it in Japanese.  She knows a little bit of English, so I tried to say "I like you how you talk almost Yakuza-style" but she didn't understand what I said.

Is there is specific way to explain a "rolling R" way of speaking in Japanese?

Please don't bother explaining how Yakuza "really talk", I'm simply asking for a specific way to reference a rolling "R" in Japanese.

How would I say "I like how you roll your 'R's" in Japanese??

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not 100% confident, but maybe you're referring to [巻【ま】き舌【じた】](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E5%B7%BB%E3%81%8D%E8%88%8C%E3%83%BB%E5%B7%BB%E8%88%8C-386779)(の口調).

Using 巻き舌 is not really special when speaking foreign languages, but 巻き舌 Japanese has a lot of "ｒ" sounds, and is often associated with yakuza-style, overpowering speech.

Use google video search with 「巻き舌 口調」 or 「巻き舌 暴言」 to hear some examples.

Comment: Hello, sorry for the late reply but yes! This is exactly what I was referring to!  Thank you so much for your detailed answer.